# divs layout / positioning is dfferent in Chrome Vs FF & IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

IE9
[image: IE9]

FireFox V22
[image]

Chrome Latest 27.0...
[image]

so as you could see it is quite same position in IE & FF but somehow Chrome is in its own domain

code is :

```
        <div id="DivLogRegForm" style="background-image: url('images/RegF.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 411px; height: 316px;">
            <div id="DivF_All" style="position:relative; top:70px;">
                <div id="DivF_User" style=" position:relative;top:13px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                    <input type="text" id="TBX_USER" style="width:205px;" />
                </div>
                <div id="DivF_Pass" style=" position:relative;top:37px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                    <input type="password" id="TBX_Pass" style="width:205px;" />
                </div>
                <div id="DivF_ConfPass" style=" position:relative;top:57px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                    <input type="password" id="TBX_ConfPass" style="width:205px;" />
                </div>
                <div id="DivF_Email" style=" position:relative;top:80px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                    <input type="text" id="TBX_Email" style="width:205px;" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

at first i tried without the 0 margin & padding but even then it did not make any difference

any suggestions how could i make it same in all of them (atleast 3 of those browsers ) ?

Comment: So each of your text fields needs to be positioned pixel-perfectly over a background image to work? That’s terribly fragile. Just make that effect using box shadows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Jr2dB/1/

```
         <div id="DivLogRegForm" style="background-image: url('images/RegF.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 411px; height: 316px;">
        <div id="DivF_All" style="position:relative; top:70px;">
            <div id="DivF_User" style=" position:absolute;top:13px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                <input type="text" id="TBX_USER" style="width:205px;" />
            </div>
            <div id="DivF_Pass" style=" position:absolute;top:37px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                <input type="password" id="TBX_Pass" style="width:205px;" />
            </div>
            <div id="DivF_ConfPass" style=" position:absolute;top:57px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                <input type="password" id="TBX_ConfPass" style="width:205px;" />
            </div>
            <div id="DivF_Email" style=" position:absolute;top:80px; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin:0 0 0 0">
                <input type="text" id="TBX_Email" style="width:205px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here seems equally broken in different browsers
but now you can fix it